# Subtract months from time in format year-month

Tags: r, date, zoo, yearmonth

I want to subtract months from given date in year and month format.

```
global_date = "2017-01"
```

I am converting it with the `zoo` library as follows:

```
as.yearmon(global_date) - 0.1
```

but it gives me Nov 2016, I want it as '201612'

How can I do it in R?

Comment: There are already answers but I would like to point out that the answer could have been found in the docs. Please see `?as.yearmon`: _The "yearmon" class is used to represent monthly data. Internally it holds the data as year plus 0 for January, 1/12 for February, 2/12 for March and so on [...]_ This tells to subtract `1/12` instead of `0.1` to go to the previous month.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As we want to subtract one month, we should subtract `1/12` which is `0.083` and not `0.1`

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(global_date) - (1/12)
#[1] "Dec 2016"
```

If we need output in the mentioned format

```
format(as.yearmon(global_date) - (1/12), "%Y%m")
#[1] "201612"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only `base R` and making only minimal changes to the OP's code

```
format(as.Date(paste0(global_date, "-01")) - 0.1*10, "%Y%m")
#[1] "201612"
```

NOTE: No external packages used

Comment: I still have that as an answer @akrun . :)

Comment: Why not just subtract 1?

Comment: @alistaire Just to make it align with the OP's post